# Firebase Analytics not showing utm* parameters

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I've set up Firebase Analytics and am successfully using dynamic deeplinks, however when I look at the attribution reports, there is no data for utm_source, utm_medium etc.

Here is an example dynamic link:

```
https://[redacted app_code].app.goo.gl/?ibi=com.[redacted hostname].FirebaseTest&ifl=http://www.[redacted hostname].com/apps&ad=1&utm_source=testsource&utm_medium=testmedium&utm_campaign=testcampaign&link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.[redacted hostname].com%2Fdeep%2Flink
```

This is the partial log with FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled:

```
2016-07-26 10:57:25.327 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the fla`g FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-07-26 10:57:25.389 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Network status has changed. Code, status: 2, Connected
2016-07-26 10:57:26.104 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
        ap = [redacted app_code];
        c = testcampaign;
        "deep_link_id" = "http://www.[redacted hostname].com/deep/link?utm_source=testsource&utm_medium=testmedium&utm_campaign=testcampaign";
        lt = "DDL_LONG";
        m = testmedium;
        s = testsource;
    }
[...]
2016-07-26 10:57:26.180 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Configuration was not found in database. The configuration will be fetched from the network when necessary
2016-07-26 10:57:26.185 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events
2016-07-26 10:57:26.188 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Setting user property. Name, value: _fot, 1469494800000
2016-07-26 10:57:26.190 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> User property set. Name, value: _fot, 1469494800000
2016-07-26 10:57:26.204 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, _f, {
        "_c" = 1;
        "_o" = auto;
    }
2016-07-26 10:57:27.354 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Event logged. Event name, event params: _f, {
        "_c" = 1;
        "_o" = auto;
    }
2016-07-26 10:57:27.374 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Timer scheduled to fire in approx. (s): 12.88030302524567
2016-07-26 10:57:27.375 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx. (s): 12.88030302524567
[...]
2016-07-26 10:57:40.553 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Launching attribution SafariViewController...
2016-07-26 10:57:40.590 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Attribution SafariViewController launched. URL: https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/app/connect/com.[redacted hostname].FirebaseTest/?app_event_type=web_bridge&idtype=idfa&lat=0&rdid=3636183D-32D6-4EA2-B4E7-998A2C459D27&sdkversion=gmp-sdk-i-v3201
2016-07-26 10:57:41.006 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Attribution SafariViewController request completed. Status: 1
2016-07-26 10:57:41.023 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Starting data upload
2016-07-26 10:57:41.039 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Saving bundle. size (bytes): 362
2016-07-26 10:57:41.040 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Bundle added to the upload queue. BundleID, timestamp (ms): 1, 1469494657413
2016-07-26 10:57:41.068 FirebaseTest[951:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Measurement data sent to network. Timestamp (ms), data: 1469494661065, <ACPMeasurementBatch 0x14e054c90>: {
        bundles {
          protocol_version: 1
          events {
            params {
              name: "_c"
              int_value: 1
            }
            params {
              name: "_o"
              string_value: "auto"
            }
            name: "_f"
            timestamp_millis: 1469494645253
          }
[... nothing in here with any utm data ...]
```

I do note the `Deep Link does not contain valid required params` part... What "required params"?

Is there something else that has to be done to see the passed in utm* data in the Attribution tab in Firebase Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, Firebase Dynamic Link already processed the URL and they should already report the campaign to Firebase Analytics. You do not need to do anything else.